# Sorting eloquent model by many-to-many relationship model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm building an application on `Laravel 5.8` where I'm having a model named `company`, `technical_description`, `state`, `region`. A company can have many locations in many state, so company and state/region are having `many-to-many` relationship. So my model looks something like this:

```php
class Company extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function states()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\State', 'company_state', 'company_id', 'state_id');
    }

    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Region', 'company_region', 'company_id', 'region_id');
    }


    public function technicalDescription()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TechnicalDescription', 'company_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

I'm now building a `data-table`, where I'm having `Company Name`, `Technical Details`, `State`, `Region` as table headers. I want to sort according to these relationships, so I tried in controller:

```php
public function companies() {
    return CompanyResource::collection(
        Company::when($request->name, function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name .'%');
        })
        ->join('company_technical_description', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_technical_description.company_id')
        ->when($request->sort_by_column, function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->orderBy($request->sort_by_column['column'], $request->sort_by_column['order'] );
        }, function ($q) use($request){
            $q->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
        })
        ->paginate();
    )
}
```

So in this case if I want to sort with any details of technical description it will be easy by simply pushing `company_technical_decription.established_date` in `$request->sort_by_column['column']`

But in case of many-to-many relationship of `state` and `region`, I'm little stuck on how can I proceed.

Help me out with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know way with `join`, worked for me with dynamic order for data tables.

You can try something like this:

```
public function companies() {
    return CompanyResource::collection(
        Company::when($request->name, function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name .'%');
        })
        ->select('companies.*', 's.name as state_name')
        ->join('company_technical_description', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_technical_description.company_id')
        ->join('company_state as cs', 'company_state.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
        ->join('states as s', 'cs.state_id', '=', 's.id')
        ->when($request->sort_by_column, function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->orderBy($request->sort_by_column['column'], $request->sort_by_column['order'] );
        }, function ($q) use($request){
            $q->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
        })
        ->paginate();
    )
}
```

I didn't test this solution but it's good for start. If you now pass `state_name` as argument for ordering, ordering should work. But I'm not sure in your database tables and columns so set your `join` to work.

I think it's good idea.

Good luck!